# ActionbarSherlock unresponsive in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` tat holds a couple of `Fragments`. Every `Fragment` has it's own menu set with 
`fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

When I rapidly hit a `MenuItem` (yes, I imported `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`), the `MenuItem` at one point stops responding, `onOptionsItemSelected` is not even called anymore.

I put a `Log.d()` in `onOptionsItemSelected` and what I saw was that, when swiping to the next `Fragment`, then all of a sudden `onOptionsItemSelected` is fired the number of times I hit the `MenuItem`, like the first `Fragment` was 'saving them up'. 
It can't have anything to do with what the item does, I let it do nothing but the problem persists.

This doesn't happen on Android 4.x but on 2 different 2.3 devices (Nexus S & HTC Wildfire).

Any ideas why this occurs and what the solution might be?

Comment: What does hitting your menu item do?

Comment: Adds / removes stuff to a certain datastructure that holds favorites and let's the user manage them (sort etc). Do you this might come from an operation that runs too long? EDIT: I tried letting the menu item do absolutely nothing, same problem.

Comment: Are you extending fragment from SherlockFragment and activity as SherlockFragmentActivity??

Comment: Yes, that's how I do it.